Separate mesh by bodies, not by faces
Say I have a lot of objects in the same mesh, one inside the other:

And with face orientation view:

I would like to separate the bodies in the mesh.
I know I could go to edit mode, select all and separate by loose parts (A > P > L), but doing so separates the inner wall from the outer wall in the objects, which is not what I want because they belong to the same body. So mesh separation is not what I'm looking for.
Is there a way to achieve this? To separate the bodies, while keeping in mind which face belongs to which object even though it's not directly touching the other faces in the body?
Please note that the real mesh I'm working with has thousands of bodies and faces and a "manual" solution like adjusting a mesh cannot work, I was wondering if there's an automated way to do this.


So you basically only want to separate the inner cubes from the surrounding object? You cannot only separate by loose parts, there is the option By Selection as well. If you need the small cubes to be separate objects, too, select one first and separate it, then select the second and separate it.

Thanks! But my real example has tens of thousands of bodies and it's not something I can adjust by hand

Then tell that in the question, because otherwise you are inviting people to give you simple solutions when you are asking about a simple problem. Neither the words nor your screenshots nor the uploaded file gives a hint on "tens of thousands of bodies". You even named the file "3bodiesProblem" as if it was mainly about those three. And what you call a "body" (a cube with an unconnected inner cube as the "inner wall") is not a single body if it is not connected.

i totally agree with Gordon - that important info is missing in your question.

Ok I understood the problem. I added another screenshot where we can see the face orientation (blue/red) so we can identify the manifold objects the OP wants to separate. Voted to reopen.

one possible way is adding one edge by selecting these two vertices and press F:

and then do A > P > L and separate by loose parts.
Then you can delete the edge afterwards if it bothers you.

Thanks! But my real example has tens of thousands of bodies and it's not something I can adjust by hand

ok, please improve your question, thx
